# Github Actions : shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0} Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully

Tags: github-actions

Here's the workflow step:

```yaml
  - name: Get files 
    id: files
    run: |
      test=$(git diff --name-only origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }} origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }})
      echo "test=$test" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I want to use the output as `steps.files.outputs.test`.

I am facing below error:

> shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
> Error: Unable to process file command 'output' successfully.

Need to get clear output. The output is in multiple lines.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? While setting it or using it? Please include this information in your question along with the same output that `test` variable holds.

Comment: I want to use the output as `steps.files.outputs.test` in next steps

Answer (score 1):

Multiline strings need a special treatment for outputs and env vars.

See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#multiline-strings

For your specific need you may want to checkout this action instead: [tj-actions/changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files)